# Browser loading indicator never stops spinning IE10

Tags: javascript, nginx

On my site I have an iframe with a self executing javascript Chatt function in it.
This script have a few setIntervals, callbacks and communicate with my NodeJs server using PushStream.

It works fine in all browsers but in, IE10 the Browser loading indicator never stops spinning, the script still works fine, but how do i get the indicator to stop?

What is different in IE10 then all the others?

The script is a few hundred lines, but here is the file.
http://westerlundh.se/cc.js

Thanks

Comment: Can you show you code?

Comment: It is a few hundred lines, but here you have the file http://westerlundh.se/cc.js

Answer (score 0):

If you have any code that runs for a long time as soon as the page is ready to execute JS this can cause the browser to keep displaying the loading indicator. Safari does/used to suffer from this issue too. A quick, but a little ugly, solution is to surround your initial code in a `setTimeout`. For instance

```
setTimeout(function(){
    //The code to run when the page loads
},10);
```

This will force IE into believing all the code that needed to be run for the page to be loaded has been run. A common cause of this (and appears to be the case for you) can be AJAX polling. Starting the first long-poll when the page is loaded causes the loading icon to display for the duration of the AJAX request being open, then starting another poll again just extends the length of time the loading icon is shown, thus looking like the page is not finished loading.